# How to use .shp file in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to create application to show offline map using GIS shape file(.shp) any one have idea  that how to use shape file to display map in android.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading data from SD card, you can work with openmap it has a class SHapefile and try to transform your shapefile to an graphicslayer it will work i've already done it.

```
static public GraphicsLayer SHPtoPOINT(String shpfile) {
    SpatialReference lSR = SpatialReference.create(26192);
    Envelope lEnvolope = getSHPEnvelope(shpfile);//to create an extent for your graphics       layer
    GraphicsLayer graphicLayer = new GraphicsLayer(lSR, lEnvolope);

    try {
        File file = new File(shpfile);
        ShapeFile shp = new ShapeFile(file);
        ESRIPointRecord e = (ESRIPointRecord) shp.getNextRecord();
        SimpleMarkerSymbol c_point = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(Color.BLACK, 1,
        STYLE.CIRCLE);
            while (e != null) {
            graphicLayer.addGraphic(new Graphic(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()), c_point));
            e = (ESRIPointRecord) shp.getNextRecord();
            }
       shp.close();
       } catch (IOException e1) {
       e1.printStackTrace();
       }
      return graphicLayer;
    }
```

[Source](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/56190-How-to-open-shape-file-%28%2a.shp%29-from-SD-Card?highlight=shapefile)

EDIT:

> BBN Technologies' OpenMap TM package is an Open Source JavaBeans TM
>   based programmer's toolkit. Using OpenMap, you can quickly build
>   applications and applets that access data from legacy databases and
>   applications. OpenMap provides the means to allow users to see and
>   manipulate geospatial information.

[Link to OpenMap info.](http://openmap.bbn.com/)

Comment: what is openmap and where can i get it?